# "For money, always decimal"?

Tags: c#, vb.net, types, finance, financial

Well, the rule "*For money, always decimal*" isn't applied inside the Microsoft development team, because if it was:

```
Namespace: Microsoft.VisualBasic
Assembly:  Microsoft.VisualBasic (in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll)
```

`Financial.IPmt` and all the other methods would receive/return `decimal` and not `double` as it is.

Now I wonder if I can use these methods without worry with round mistakes?

Should I use some other libraries to work with finances? If yes, could you point me some good ones (for `C#` use) ?

Comment: My totally-not-a-VB-user guess would be that the Financial library probably handles storage correctly internally, but I wouldn't bet on it. You would want to check if internal handling is consistent or not before just condemning it on the basis of return type.

Comment: My vote is for boolean - you either have money or you don't ;-)

Comment: For money, always decimal is ***golden rule*** ? forever ?

Comment: @Kiquenet well, personally this is what I use based on all the things I have read in the past written by people theoretically with more knowledge in this matter than me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this class:

```
public class Financial
{
    #region Methods

    public static decimal IPmt(decimal Rate, decimal Per, decimal NPer, decimal PV, decimal FV, FinancialEnumDueDate Due)
    {
        decimal num;
        if (Due != FinancialEnumDueDate.EndOfPeriod)
        {
            num = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            num = 1;
        }
        if ((Per <= 0) || (Per >= (NPer + 1)))
        {
            //Argument_InvalidValue1=

            throw new ArgumentException("Argument 'Per' is not a valid value.");
        }
        if ((Due != FinancialEnumDueDate.EndOfPeriod) && (Per == 1))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        decimal pmt = Pmt(Rate, NPer, PV, FV, Due);
        if (Due != FinancialEnumDueDate.EndOfPeriod)
        {
            PV += pmt;
        }
        return (FV_Internal(Rate, Per - num, pmt, PV, FinancialEnumDueDate.EndOfPeriod) * Rate);
    }

    public static decimal PPmt(decimal Rate, decimal Per, decimal NPer, decimal PV, decimal FV, FinancialEnumDueDate Due)
    {
        if ((Per <= 0) || (Per >= (NPer + 1)))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Argument 'Per' is not valid.");
        }
        decimal num2 = Pmt(Rate, NPer, PV, FV, Due);
        decimal num = IPmt(Rate, Per, NPer, PV, FV, Due);
        return (num2 - num);
    }

    static decimal FV_Internal(decimal Rate, decimal NPer, decimal Pmt, decimal PV, FinancialEnumDueDate Due)
    {
        decimal num;
        if (Rate == 0)
        {
            return (-PV - (Pmt * NPer));
        }
        if (Due != FinancialEnumDueDate.EndOfPeriod)
        {
            num = 1 + Rate;
        }
        else
        {
            num = 1;
        }
        decimal x = 1 + Rate;
        decimal num2 = (decimal)Math.Pow((double)x, (double)NPer);
        return ((-PV * num2) - (((Pmt / Rate) * num) * (num2 - 1)));
    }

    static decimal Pmt(decimal Rate, decimal NPer, decimal PV, decimal FV, FinancialEnumDueDate Due)
    {
        decimal num;
        if (NPer == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Argument NPer is not a valid value.");
        }
        if (Rate == 0)
        {
            return ((-FV - PV) / NPer);
        }
        if (Due != FinancialEnumDueDate.EndOfPeriod)
        {
            num = 1 + Rate;
        }
        else
        {
            num = 1;
        }
        decimal x = Rate + 1;
        decimal num2 = (decimal)Math.Pow((double)x, (double)NPer);
        return (((-FV - (PV * num2)) / (num * (num2 - 1))) * Rate);
    }

    #endregion Methods
}
```

Comment: Hi there, what is the Per variable for?

Comment: @cbp Please see the VB function for [PPmt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.financial.ppmt.aspx), which matches the `PPmt` function here (2nd function), which calls `IPmt`.

Answer (score 10):

Here's an interesting discussion regarding exactly this topic: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=524101

About 1/3 of the way down someone explains that it uses Double because the VB.NET functions were implemented to work exactly the same as VB6. VB6 doesn't have a decimal type, which is why it uses double.

**So, it seems that if accuracy is important, you *should not* use these functions.**

<strike>The answers to [this question](https://web.archive.org/web/20100727035953/http://stackoverflow.com:80/questions/326649/c-financial-functions-library) have some promising alternatives - just ignore the accepted answer that suggests using the VB library.</strike>

The previously linked question has been deleted, so here are some of the suggestions I was referencing (note: I have not tried these, YMMV)

- [Implementations of excel financial functions in F# - can be used from any .NET language, does not require F# reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dsyme/net-implementations-of-excel-financial-functions-in-f)
- [QuantLib](https://sourceforge.net/projects/quantlib/) may be able to be exported/generated for C#. [See this SO question/answer for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334011/compiling-quantlib-via-swig-for-c-sharp)

Comment: VB6 does have a Currency type though, which is an Int64 with four implied decimal places.

Comment: I decided to write my own finance methods with decimal values.
Red Gate's.Net Reflector as a helpful tool :D

Answer (score 10):

The rule to use `decimal` for money is helpful because most currencies have decimal units.  By using decimal arithmetic, you avoid introducing and accumulating round-off error.

[Financial Class functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.financial.aspx) use floating-point for a few reasons:

- They don't internally accumulate -- they are based on a closed-form exponential/logarithmic computation, not iteration and summation over periods.
- They tend not to use or produce exact decimal values.  For example, an exact decimal annual interest rate divided by 12 monthly payments becomes a repeating decimal.
- They are intended primarily for decision support, and in the end have little applicability to actual bookkeeping.

`Pmt` and rounding may determine the nominal monthly payment, but once that amount is determined, balance accumulation -- payments made, interest charges applied, etc. -- happens in `decimal`.  Also, late or advance payments, payment holidays, and other such non-uniformities would invalidate the projected amortization provided by the financial functions.