# Compiling Quantlib via SWIG for C#

Tags: c#, c++, com-interop, swig, quantlib

Anyone have any experience using [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/)? I am currently researching [QuantLib](http://quantlib.org/index.shtml) and saw that C# code can be generated using SWIG. We are exploring options to create a combined library of financial functions using QuantLib and  a proprietary closed source library (which will probably be made available as .Net dlls). The idea is to combine both of these to create a unified super library. I have seen the [.Net port of QuantLib](http://www.qlnet.org/), but it seems that it is not actively maintained (and not entirely sure of how much was actually ported), so I am avoiding it.

Step 1 of this is to evaluate the difficulty in producing a library that can be used 'anywhere' i.e. MS office applications ( via VBA), console apps as well server-side (eg web apps). I assume that this involves COM Interop, but I have no clue where to start or if I am even on the right track.

I have no experience with C++; and COM is something (a buzzword to me at the moment) that I have glazed over. I am aware of the relevant MSDN articles related to this topic.

I am looking for help along the following lines:

1. Are there alternatives to using QuantLib in C#?
2. With respect to my development environment, what would I need?
3. Does anyone know of a ready-to-use QuantLib C# library compiled via SWIG? (first prize = less work for me)

Any help appreciated?

**Edit:** I have accepted my answer as the correct one unless there is a better one provided.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So it would seem that the C# bindings for SWIG are available. One needs to **browse** the [SVN repository or list of files on SouceForge](http://quantlib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/quantlib/trunk/?sortby=date) to find them.

The SWIG folder contains several subfolders, depending on your language of choice, in my case C# was the one that interested me. You will need to download SWIG first and it the executable to system `PATH` variable.

Make sure to read the `Readme.txt` as it contains details about the `QL_DIR` environment variable that also needs to be created.

This may be a limitation of VS Express - but the solution file contains both the C# project and C++ project, of which only either the C# or C++ portions can be opened at any time. My suggestion would be to created separate solution files for the C++ and the C# projects.

Coming from a .Net background, lib files, obj files and the all the other jazz associated with c++ takes some time to getting use to.

### Steps taken to get a working C# library

1. Download QuantLib and Boost as described [here](http://quantlib.org/install/vc9.shtml)
2. Download the tar ball of the [QuantLib-SWIG folder from SourceForge](http://quantlib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/quantlib/trunk/QuantLib-SWIG/?sortby=dateBlockquote). **Edit:** There is a [download of the zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/quantlib/files/QuantLib/1.0/bindings/QuantLib-SWIG-1.0.zip/download) available on the home page. Its listed within the subfolders. Check the v1.0 folders under `Bindings`
3. Run the `swig.cmd` file located in `QuantLib-SWIG\CSharp` folder (you need to download SWIG first() --> this generates the cs wrapper files for Quantlib.
4. Build the c++ project `NQuantLibc` - note the dll created here needs to be always shipped with the NQuantlib C# built dll. It needs to be placed in a location that is readable by the  `DLLImport` attribute. (See [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586(VS.85).aspx) for list of locations)
5. Build the C# project `NQuantLib`

***With respect to my development environment, what would I need?***

<strike>It seems that the current version of QuantLib only builds with VS 2008. There have been some changes to VS 2010 which causes some issues with compilation. The C# project builds fine, however just remember to change the Target Framework from v4 to v3.5 to lower.</strike>

Note: As the time of writing this there was an issue with the `QL_HEX_VERSION` number in the source files of the C++ SWIG project. After running the `swig.cmd` open the VS project, and change Line 344 of `quantlib_wrap.cpp` to

```
#if QL_HEX_VERSION < 0x010001f0//0x010100f0
```

I have emailed the project author, and awaiting feedback. **Edit:** Luigi, correctly informed me that this is any issue with the code in SVN (which I used). He suggested that the [QuantLib-SWIG-1.0.zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/quantlib/files/QuantLib/1.0/bindings/QuantLib-SWIG-1.0.zip/download) bindings should be used.

Quantlib also build on [VC++ 2010](http://quantlib.org/install/vc10.shtml) with the latest release.

Comment: Hi Ahmad can you explain me what you mean with "It needs to be placed in a location that is readable by the DLLImport attribute."? I did everything you said but at runtime I get a [pInvokeStackImbalance error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0htdy0k3.aspx) at multiple locations in the C# classes. I'm using the latest QuantLib/Boost libraries in VS2010.

Comment: Firstly, AFAIK VS2010 cannot be used to compile Quantlib as yet - it is being worked at the moment but not yet ready. Use VS2008 or lower. The VS Express version works perfectly fine. See the update regarding the dll location

Comment: The following thread may be of use as well: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.finance.quantlib.user/8238

Comment: I think some of these comments are outdated. I could successfully build Quantlib with VS2010.