# Quantlib 64-bit for C#?

Tags: c#, c++, 64-bit, quantlib

Just discovered Quantlib and am evaluating it for use.  I am not a C++ developer, and no one on staff where I work really has deep experience with it, so I am pretty much following the instructions by rote found here:

http://quantlib.org/install/vc10.shtml

The next step will be to convert to C# using SWIG (based on instructions found here: [Compiling Quantlib via SWIG for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334011/compiling-quantlib-via-swig-for-c-sharp)).

My question is, when I have completed all of the steps listed in both posts, will the result be a library that can only be compiled as 32-bit?  The Boost download seems to indicate that it is 32-bit only.

Is compiling as a 64-bit application possible and/or are 64-bit binaries available anywhere (Windows platform) and/or are alternative wrapper libraries (like QLNet) a good alternative?

Comment: does the vendor offer a 32 bit version of the assemblies or .dll's that you are wanting or needing.. ?

Comment: I can't find the library pre-built anywhere (there is one, but it's an old version).  In any case, I need it to be 64-bit.

Comment: Question do you have access to the actual 64 bit SRC.? here is something that might help if not then .. I am not sure what you should do.. http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2011/04/04/

Comment: Interfacing quantlib with C#/.NET? Re-post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380167/whats-the-best-to-call-quantlib-methods-from-c-sharp/21177527#21177527

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a regular user of QuantLib. Why would you convert QuantLib to C#??? There's QLNet, which is a direct port of the library in C#. Regarding about 64 bits, you just need to compile the source yourself.

Comment: We have no C++ expertise in-house, so having a .Net library would be beneficial for many reasons.  I am aware of QLNet as noted in my original question--what I need to know is whether it is a viable substitute.  I can't find a lot of info on the subject.

Comment: QLNet is a good alternative. It's a direct port of QuantLib. Not everything is ported. But the whole framework is done. It's open source, anything you don't want, just do it yourself. Overall, it's a very good subtitution. I have experience in it.