# Why Does The NET Financial Library Use Doubles?

Tags: .net, decimal, currency

I always read if its about money and currencies use decimal.

So why does Microsoft.VisualBasic.Financial only take doubles as arguments?

> public static double PV (double Rate, double NPer, double Pmt, double
> FV = 0, Microsoft.VisualBasic.DueDate Due =
> Microsoft.VisualBasic.DueDate.EndOfPeriod);

From the docs. Rate, Pmt and FV are all money.

Comment: Wild guess: Because it's something ported from VB 6 where there was no Decimal (so converted projects can behave the same wrong way as they did under VB 6...)

Comment: See [“For money, always decimal”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604003/for-money-always-decimal). Not marking this one as a duplicate, since 10 years passed since the other question, so there may be newer angles to this (though I guess @gsharp's VB6 hunch may be right on the money).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "why is product done like this" is only answerable by the authors.